# RedHat Enterprise 5.6 trial install KVM

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, kvm-virtualization

I am trying to run KVM on RedHat Enterprise Linux 5.6 trial, and I tried following the tutorial in http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-rhel-linux-kvm-virtulization-tutorial/

If I do yum groupinfo KVM
the system cannot find anything,
and I also tried searching for KVM from the Add/Remove Software with no luck.

Do I need to download some other bits from redhat so I can run KVM?

Comment: Are you registered with RHN?  Does `yum grouplist` return anything at all?

Comment: The trials i've been given at courses come with a 30day rhn code on the back of the red box.

Answer (score 1):

On Centos, you would go:

```
yum -y groupinstall Virtualization
```

If  you registered for the RHN trial, it may be the same command. However, it may be simpler just to install Centos 5.x instead.

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation appears to suggest that kvm is a package rather than a package group. It also mentions that you must have the system registered to rhn, I would assume even on the trial this is correct.

http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Virtualization/sect-Virtualization-Installing_the_virtualization_packages-Installing_KVM_packages_on_an_existing_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_system.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RHEL 5.X version then you need to have RHN account or there is work around you can install KVM

```
    Step # 1: Mount an ISO file.

    # mkdir -p /media/centos
    # mount -o loop /dev/centos6X.iso /media/centos

    Step # 2: Create repo config file on both the node.

    # vi /etc/yum.repos.d/iso.repo
    [ISO]
    baseurl=file:///media/centos
    enabled=1

    Save and close the file

# yum install kvm virt-viewer virt-manager libvirt libvirt-python python-virtinst

OR

# yum groupinstall KVM
```

above one of way to install or you can use CentOS 6.2 for GUI installation and choose packes